# Drawing line animating vertical circle using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate an object on button click and also want to drawing a vertical line .animate its working fine ..but i am facing problem to drawing line How can I do this in jQuery can any one suggest me?

```
<script>
  $("#clickaroo").click(
    function() {
      $("#movaroo").animate(
        { top: "+=234px" }, 1000);
    }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: `vertical line` where?

Comment: drawing line is fine but where, as a border or as strike out or on canvas or where exactly , please elaborate ?

Comment: during the object moving from vertically ...till height from top 234 px

Comment: you can say as border or strike out or as just simple line to represent the height from top to 234 px...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a `div` with just a `border` of 1px so that it looks like a line , and position it using CSS at the right position.

When the DOM is ready , just hide it using the `$(selector).hide();` function , and when you want to make it appear you can use the jquery's `sildeDown()` function to get the effect.

so the code can be something like this

**HTML**

```
<button id="clickaroo">click me</button>
<div id="hiddenDiv">
```

**CSS**( you may have to change the CSS to correctly position the "line" as per your needs)

```
#hiddenDiv{
    margin:0 50%;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    height:234px;
    top:0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
$('#hiddenDiv').hide();
});  

$("#clickaroo").click(
    function() {
      $("#movaroo").animate(
        { top: "+=234px" }, 1000);
        $('#hiddenDiv').slideDown(1000);
       /* $('#hiddenDiv').slideToggle(1000); you can also use this*/
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of how you can do it. Please check it out to get an idea. If you are having difficulties you will need to edit the post and provide more information regarding what you are trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/WhKbs/

```
<div id="line" style="width:0; height:0; border:1px solid #000000"></div>

$('#line').animate({height: 234}, 1000);
```